# Create global pointer to specific memory address in LLVM IR

Tags: llvm, avr, llvm-ir

I'm experimenting with LLVM IR as an alternative to assembly for programming AVR chips, but I have encountered a stumbling block.

I have the following working code:

```
target triple = "avr-atmel-none"

define void @main() {
    %1 = load i8, i8* inttoptr (i8 34 to i8*)
    %or = or i8 %1, 1
    store i8 %or, i8* inttoptr (i8 34 to i8*)
    ret void
}
```

Notice the `inttoptr (i8 34 to i8*)` - that's a memory-mapped IO location on my chip, which I will interact with a lot, so I'd like to give it a name like `@PORTA`. However, I can't find a way to initialise a global variable as pointing to a specific memory address. This *doesn't* work:

```
@PORTA = constant i8* inttoptr (i8 34 to i8*)
```

as it initialises the *contents* of a pointer variable `@PORTA`, rather than creating it pointing to that address.

Is it possible to make a global alias for a certain memory address in LLVM IR? If not, is there some other shortcut that would allow me to alias these names?

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need to create such alias on IR level? LLVM IR isn't supposed to be comfortable to write manually.

If you are generating code from C++ API then just make that `inttoptr` constant expression global and use it wherever you like:

```
ConstantExpr* porta = ...

void foo()
{
new LoadInst(..., porta);
...
new StoreInst(..., porta);
}
```

Comment: Assembly isn't "comfortable" to write manually either, but for some microcontroller projects it's a useful tool. I'm considering whether IR would be useful as basically better-typed and more modular version of assembly. And no, I'm not using the API.

Comment: Then consider using DSL-like bindings to LLVM. IIRC, there is one for Python. I was developing this kind of stuff long ago for Haskell and while it is unusable now, it should give an idea: https://bitbucket.org/arrowd/llvm-general-edsl/src/78228725331215b1eef8a8319ab7d7d3acae4ec2/src/LLVM/General/EDSL.hs?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: @felixphew why now C instead, IR & assembler will not give you any advantage.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I do normally use C for these projects, but I'm interested to see what can be done this way. "IR & assembler will not give you any advantage." That's patently not true - for example certain tricks with the interrupt addresses are extremely cumbersome in C.

Comment: @felixphew maybe it the correct time to start with 32 processors? Cheaper, faster, better peripherals :). No tricks needed. BTW what tricks? I do not see any which cant be done with C

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Running into an inconvenience in an experiment is no reason to switch to a totally different class of chip, when the ones I'm using are meeting all my needs just fine. I appreciate you're trying to be helpful, but insisting I have a different problem is not the same thing as helping solve the question I do have.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 As for "what tricks?", one example would be attaching the same ISR to multiple interrupts. Ugly and messy in C (with avr-libc anyway), but just a `jmp` (or even a `nop`) in assembly.

Comment: @felixphew Another solution would be using C preprocessor and manually invoking `cc -E` before `llc`.